# What I need to write in schema.xml for searching in two or more fields in Solr?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, solr

I'm new in Solr.
I've indexed 3 fields from MySql to solr.
Id, first_name, last_name.
I want to search in first_name and last_name.
In schema.xml I wrote:

```
<fields>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="first_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="last_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>first_name</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

What I have to write here for searching first in first_name and after in last_name.
Where I have to give priorities for fields?
Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define this on the query. I recomend you to use a requestHandler for this:

```
<requestHandler name="bcn_jug_en" class="solr.SearchHandler" enable="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="qf">first_name^10 last_name^5</str>
   <str name="mm">100%</str>
</lst>
```

http://searchhub.org/2010/05/23/whats-a-dismax/

Comment: I have to add this in solconfig.xml?

Comment: It's a example of requestHandler. You can define your own similar to this so you define relevance of the fields in the search and the possibility to search in several fields